# How to change the size and position of popover's page in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, popover, swiftui

I want to set the position and size of Popover page.

I tried all parameters of  func popover, I think it may be related with attachmentAnchor and arrowEdge.

Here is my code:

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView : View {
        @State var isPop = false

        var body: some View {

            VStack{
                Button("Pop", action: {self.isPop = true})
                    .popover(isPresented: $isPop,  attachmentAnchor: .point(UnitPoint(x: 20, y: 20)), arrowEdge: .top, content: {return Rectangle().frame(height: 100).foregroundColor(Color.blue)})
            }

        }

    }
```

The effect I want:

[image]

Comment: Yes, attachmentAnchor provides an offset for the popover, with respect to the anchor point. If I remember correctly, you need to use `arrowEdge: .bottom` instead of `.top`., as you are anchoring on the bottom part of the button. As for the size, I did not find a way.

Comment: Any progress on that? I tried everything, and for now the size is always the same default one. I hope they'll fix in B6

Comment: Not yet, I put the problem aside.

Comment: There is solution, please check answer. + @Dimillian.

Answer (score 8):

Here is kind of correct configuration

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPop = false
    @State private var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Pop") { self.isPop.toggle() }
                .popover(isPresented: $isPop,
                         attachmentAnchor: .point(.bottom),   // here !
                         arrowEdge: .bottom) {                // here !!
                    VStack { // just example
                        Text("Test").padding(.top)
                        TextField("Placeholder", text: self.$text)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .padding(.bottom)
                            .frame(width: 200)
                    }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The `attachmentAnchor` is in UnitPoint, ie in 0..1 range with predefined constants, and `arrowEdge` is just Edge, to which popover arrow is directed. And size of popover is defined by internal content, by default it tights to minimal, but using standard .padding/.frame modifiers it can be extended to whatever needed.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I found that worked is putting `padding` around the button and then `offset`. I needed the offset to reposition the button correctly after the padding was put in. So depending on your design just a padding should work. `ArrowEdge` parameter and `attactmentAnchor` are also important but default work well for me with the popover below the button.

For example:

```
VStack {
    Button("Pop", action: {self.isPop = true})
        .padding(.bottom, 6) // add in padding to position the popover
        .popover(isPresented: $isPop,  attachmentAnchor: .point(UnitPoint(x: 20, y: 20)), arrowEdge: .top, content: {return Rectangle().frame(height: 100).foregroundColor(Color.blue)})
}
```

Comment: According to Apple, A unit point with one or more components outside the range [0, 1] projects to a point outside of the view.(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/unitpoint)