# Is there a way to create a popup window with only SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui, popup, window

I am working on a calendar app for MacOS, using SwiftUI, and I was wondering if there is a way to create a popup like the built-in calendar app has? (See below image)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60903302/12299030?

Comment: I think it could work. Let me try it out. Thanks!